# ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' when using browserify

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

I am building a web app and want to use node.js to build it.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>My Class</title>
</head>
<body>
     <p class="myClass" id="myID">Click Here</p>

<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js file:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");

const { myVar } = require("./ither.js");

document.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // DO SOMETHING
});
```

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
  },
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/express": "^4.17.17"
}
```

When I run the `js` file (`node index.js`) I am getting `ReferenceError: document is not defined` error on my **terminal** and on my **browser** I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error.

After some research, I read about `browserify` and did the following:

`npm install -g browserify`

`src/index.js > src/bundle.js`

This is the error I am getting:

```
/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is using ES modules syntax (import and export statements), but the environment where you're running the code does not support ES modules by default.

Install Browserify and Babelify:

```
npm install --save-dev browserify babelify
```

Update your JavaScript file (index.js) to use CommonJS modules instead of ES modules. Replace the import statements with require statements. For example, instead of `import axios from "axios`";, use `const axios = require("axios")`;.

Update your package.json file to set the "type" field to "module" and remove the "require" package from the dependencies:

```
json

{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17"
  }
}
```

Bundle your code with Browserify using Babelify:

```
npx browserify src/index.js -o src/bundle.js -t babelify
```

Update your HTML file to reference the bundled JavaScript file:

```
  <script src="src/bundle.js"></script>
```

This should be able to bundle your code with Browserify and run it in the browser without encountering errors.